# draw a smooth dendrite

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I want to draw a dendrite and here is what I have done till now,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\newcommand*{\hd}{1.0}%
\newcommand*{\vd}{1.5}%

\begin{document}


  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
    \draw (0,0) -- (\hd,0)--(\hd,\vd) -- (2*\hd, \vd) -- (2*\hd, 0) -- (3*\hd, 0) --(3*\hd, \vd)--(4*\hd, \vd) --(4*\hd, 0) --(5*\hd, 0) ;
 \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[rotate=270,shift = {(-5*\hd,0.75*\vd)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (\hd,0)--(\hd,\vd) -- (2*\hd, \vd) -- (2*\hd, 0) -- (3*\hd, 0) --(3*\hd, \vd)--(4*\hd, \vd) --(4*\hd, 0) --(5*\hd, 0) ;
 \end{scope}
 \draw(0,3.333*\vd) --(1.1*\hd,3.333*\vd);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is very elementary set-up where I found it difficult to make corners of the dendrites smooth. To get a half dendrite and make the smooth corners  , I thought to make a periodic function (a parabola e.g.) and make a collection of them shifted by a distance and then rotating the set but I am not able to plot parabolas side by side.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post an image of the desired result? Googling for images of dendrites revealed not very helpful.

Comment: You might try the [`hobby` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby), which lets you "draw" a smooth path by specifying a relatively small number of points on the paths (with tangent angles if desired).

Comment: @JLDiaz, the desired result can be seen at end of the question.

Comment: @alekhine Oh, sorry, I thought that it was the output of your code. It looked good enough to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this close enough?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, x=4mm]
  \draw[y= 4mm, rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.5) \foreach \i in {0,...,10} 
    { -- ++(0.25,5-0.4*\i) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0.25, -5+0.4*\i) -- ++(0.5,0) }
    -- ++(0.3,1) to[bend left=10] ++(2,-1.5);
  \draw[y=-4mm, rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.5) \foreach \i in {0,...,10} 
    { -- ++(0.25,5-0.4*\i) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0.25, -5+0.4*\i) -- ++(0.5,0) }
    -- ++(0.3,1) to[bend right=10] ++(2,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Much Better than I thought..!! thank you very much jLDiaz..!!