# How to draw 2D dendrite shape with surface normal?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found another answer to draw a smooth dendrite: [draw a smooth dendrite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182952/draw-a-smooth-dendrite)

I would like some help extending this to produce a schematic of the dendrite shown below with a border and a surface normal. My idea is to copy the dendrite code from the answer above and rotate it. However, I am having trouble creating the center section.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to use the other answer to patch together a continuous path. I do not have the time for fine-tuning. You just copy the path from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182952/draw-a-smooth-dendrite) and make it a style using `insert path`. The patches can then be moved and rotated and, what is important here, combined to a longer path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.4,
 dentrite leg/.style={insert path={% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182966/121799
    foreach \X in {0,...,10} 
    { -- ++(0.25,5-0.4*\X) -- ++(0.5,0) -- ++(0.25, -5+0.4*\X) -- ++(0.5,0) }
    -- ++(0.3,1) to[out=0,in=135] ++(2,-1.5) coordinate(dentrite-top-#1)
    to[out=-135,in=0] ++(-2,-1.5)   -- ++(-0.3,1)
    foreach \X in {10,9,...,0} 
    { -- ++(-0.5,0)-- ++(-0.25, -5+0.4*\X)-- ++(-0.5,0)  -- ++(-0.25,5-0.4*\X)  }
    }}]
  \path foreach \X in {0,1,2,3} {(45-90*\X:6) + (-45-90*\X:-0.5)coordinate (X\X)};
   \draw[fill=green!70!blue,rotate=45,rounded corners=1mm] (X0) [dentrite leg=0] 
   [rotate=-90] to[out=45,in=-225] (X1)   [dentrite leg=1]
   [rotate=-90] to[out=45,in=-225] (X2)   [dentrite leg=2]
   [rotate=-90] to[out=45,in=-225] (X3)   [dentrite leg=3]
   [rotate=-90] to[out=45,in=-135] cycle;
   \draw[-latex] (dentrite-top-3) -- ++ (135:1) node[above left]{$\vec n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that this may not be the final version of the picture you are after. You will need to tune things here and there to arrive there, I focused on the simple things.